# How to modify my python socket server code to accommodate two clients?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, communication

I am trying to send data from my Client_1 to Client-2. This transmission will have to occur through the server program. The transmission of the data from Client_1 to the server is successful, but the server is not able to connect to Client_2. Please note that, for my application **SERVER IS ACTING LIKE A PASSIVE ELEMENT, NOT AS AN ACTIVE ELEMENT ** i.e., the server is not proactively sending or broadcasting any data. It is just acting like a bridge between Client_1 and Client_2.

My problem is how to modify my server code so that I am able to connect both my clients with my server and should be able to transfer the received data in server to Client_2.

Below I am attaching my server code::

```
import socket
#from threading import Thread

def server_program():

    all_connections = []
    all_address = []

    host = socket.gethostname()       ###### get the hostname ###########
    port = 5000                   ##################### initiate port no above 1024 ###############
    server_socket = socket.socket()                 ############# initiate the connection ##########e

    server_socket.bind((host, port))     ############### bind host address and port together ##############

            ############### configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously ################
    server_socket.listen(5)


    #def accepting_connections():
     #   for c in all_connections:
      #      c.close()

    #del all_connections[:]
    #del all_address[:]


    conn, address = server_socket.accept() 
   # socket.setblocking(1)
    all_connections.append(conn)
    all_address.append(address)
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
                                     ################ receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes ###########
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
                                        ########### if data is not received break #############
             break
        print("from housekeeping unit: " + str(data))
                # data = input(' -> ')
        conn.send(data.encode())  ########## send data to the client ###########

    conn.close() ############## close the connection ###############


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Comment: Try using the `select` module. This will allow you to accept a client socket, and keep the server open for listening for more connections.

Answer (score -1):

see the module multiprocessing (https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)